# How to get the id on one specific channel in my telegram group?

Tags: bots, telegram

I have a telegram group that has multiple sub-group inside it, how do I get the id of a specific sub group for my bot to send message to it ? Thanks !

I tried going to telegram web but all sub groups have the same ID

Thanks for your help